# How to catch keyerror and execute the rest of code if keyerror equals to zero

Tags: python, api

I am trying to write a function that checks if the given variable is country name, city name, or some rubbish word. first I check if the variable is the country name. for that, I use an API. If the variable is not in the list of the country names I want to check it in the cities name list. The problem is that if the variable name does not exist it return a key error : 0 error and I cannot move to pass that and insert my city name checking code. Is there any way to get around this? This is what I have tired

```
def searchCountry():
    try:
        address = 'berlin'
        checkcountry = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/' + address 
        json_data = requests.get(checkcountry).json()
        new_address  = json_data[0]['name']['common']
    except KeyError as e:
        try:
            if e == 0:
                checkcities =  'https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries'
                json_data = requests.get(checkcities).json()
                cities_list = []
                for i in range(0,len(json_data['data'])):
                    list = json_data['data'][i]['cities']
                    cities_list.append(list)
                new_list=sum(cities_list, [])
                for item in new_list:
                    if address == item:
                        return address
                    else:
                        print('error')
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: If you want to work around the key error with `.get()` let me know and I can show you and example.

Comment: Yeah sure,if you want @JonSG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not guaranteed from other types reusing it, `dict` generated `KeyError`s pass the missing key as the sole argument to the constructor for `KeyError`, and like all exceptions, it stores its arguments as a `tuple` in the `.args` attribute. So all you need to do is replace:

```
if e == 0:
```

with:

```
if e.args[0] == 0:
# Or to be absolutely sure it wasn't constructed with additional arguments:
if e.args == (0,):  # Trailing comma mandatory to make it an actual one-tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of cleanup we can do to guard against ever running into the key error using `get()`. While we are at it, let's also query the country/city API once and get all the data and cache it so that repeated requests are faster.

This technique is often called a closure.

```py
import requests

## -------------------------------
## Use a closure to fetch and cache coutry/city data
## -------------------------------
def build_country_searcher():
    checkcities =  'https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries'
    response = requests.get(checkcities)

    if not response.ok:
        raise Exception("failed to fetch data")

    ## -------------------------------
    ## Construct lookups for counties and cities once and cache results
    ## -------------------------------
    countries = set()
    city_to_country = {}
    for country in response.json().get("data", []):
        country_name = country["country"]

        countries.add(country_name)

        for city in country["cities"]:
            city_to_country.setdefault(city, []).append(country_name)
    ## -------------------------------

    ## -------------------------------
    ## hidden utility function to just look up if the given name
    ## is a country. Note, we could also have used the abo
    ## -------------------------------
    def check_country(name):
        return name if name in countries else None
    ## -------------------------------

    ## -------------------------------
    ## Note that a city could be found in many countries so for
    ## fun, let's return those counties as a comma separated list.
    ## -------------------------------
    def check_city(name):
        return ", ".join(city_to_country.get(name, []))
    ## -------------------------------

    ## -------------------------------
    ## return our function that will process the lookups.
    ## -------------------------------
    return lambda name: check_country(name) or check_city(name) or None
    ## -------------------------------
## -------------------------------

## -------------------------------
## Build out search function
## -------------------------------
country_searcher = build_country_searcher()
## -------------------------------

print(country_searcher("Germany"))
print(country_searcher("Berlin"))
print(country_searcher("Middle Earth"))
```

This should give you back:

```
Germany
Germany, United States
None
```